# What is the hardest bodyweight chest exercise?

Tags: strength, bodyweight-exercises, chest

By "the hardest bodyweight chest exercise", I mean the one that requires the most amount of skill and strength. Is there a bodyweight chest equivalent to the handstand pushup or the front lever, for example? Thank you.

Comment: How would you define "hardest" here? Sounds like something that would be different for different people.

Comment: @Alec I defined it in the question: the one that requires the most skill and strength. Fot example, the front lever is almost objectively harder than the pullup, because it requires more strength than the pullup, and requires that one be able to balance using their hands as a lever. The V-sit is objectively harder than the L-sit, because it requires more strength and flexibility to lift the legs up to a v-shape than it does to an l-shape. The iron cross is considered the hardest gymnastics move, because it requires the most strength and skill to execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if there is a "chest equivalent" to a handstand pushup or front lever, it's either a full planche or maltese. (or the push up variants of both exercises)

Both exercises require a lot more than just chest though, so they aren't JUST a chest exercise, but they require a lot of power and skill to perform.

I would say that of these two exercises, the planche push-ups require more power from the chest than a maltese, which is more shoulder power than chest. I have to add that I can't do a maltese yet so I haven't experienced the movement myself, but I've done some iron cross progression and I'm assuming the maltese is somewhat similar to that.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have gotten it from many other sources, and so I appreciate you coroborrating it. The answer, then, is certain.